# Does applying for a multiple entry Schengen visa instead of a single entry the first time hurt my chances of a visa getting granted?

Tags: visas, schengen, eu

While applying for a Schengen visa, an option is given to choose between a single entry visa or a multiple entry visa. There isn't any published policy on this, but if it's the first time time I'm applying for a Schengen visa does it hurt my chance of getting one in case I say I want to get a multiple entry visa instead of single entry?

(By 'hurt' I mean say I ask for multiple entry and a stricter rule is used for checking whether the visa is granted, then will I be given a single entry visa instead or will the whole application be rejected?)

Comment: I got a 6 month Multiple Entry by the French. I have a Pakistani passport. I live and work in London. I was very happy and surprised too. I also gave an annual multi trip insurance. That might have helped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're unlikely to get a definitive answer to this question, since the exact internal visa criteria are not published.  So take all advice you get with a grain of salt.

So.  Most countries do indeed treat multiple-entry status as an optional bonus of sorts: if you're borderline, instead of rejecting the application outright, you'll get a single entry instead.  My *understanding* is that the EU does this as well, but it would not hurt to ask the embassy before applying.

That said, if you're only a casual tourist and/or a first-time visitor, you're unlikely to get a multiple entry as your first visa.  Providing an itinerary that requires you to depart and re-enter Schengen (eg. Paris-London-Paris), preferably with some of proof that you really are going to do something legitimate (letters from business partners, conference registration, etc), may help.

Comment: Nowadays there seem to be three options for schengen visas: 1 entry, 2 entries and multiple entry. So for Paris-London-Paris itineraries, a two-entry visa would probably be issued.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same question and decided to ask the embassy in London. They said I can ask whatever I want, but they have the rights to grant or deny your request. You can ask for multiple entries for 6 months and that's not a problem at all.

However, by denial if they think it's not appropriate to grant whatever you requested. At least, they will grant the visa according to your travel plan. And I have done that multiple times. Never got rejected once.

Answer (score 3):

Before talking about single/multiple entry, the Schengen visa duration given to an individual depends on the duration applicant wishes to stay. One needs to provide the documents which detail about accommodation, tickets (both onward and return), countries of entry and exit. In recent past, Schengen visa is issued only for the duration and additional two-three days.

As per my sources, earlier applicants were given a six months visa. But now the visa duration will be applicant's duration of stay plus another two to three days.