# Multiple Entry Schengen Visa Tier-4 UK

Tags: visas, schengen, london, indonesian-citizens, multiple-entry

I have a Tier 4 Student Visa for the UK and am an Indonesian national studying in NYU London for 6 months.

What will I need to ensure and provide to make sure I get the multiple entry visa as well as anything I should do to increase my chances?

I'm planning on applying through the Czech embassy in London as it will be my point of entry and the country I'll be spending most of my time in for the Schengen area.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5538/does-applying-for-a-multiple-entry-schengen-visa-instead-of-a-single-entry-the-f?rq=1

Comment: Generally speaking single people are more of a concern, so: A return ticket, a job offer from Indonesia would go a long way all that all these agencies are looking for is that you will leave.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, multiple entry visa are given to individuals who already received several single-entry visa beforehand. It is unlikely that you will receive one just after having one single, even unused single-entry visa in your passport.

In general, those visa are given only to reduce workload at the visa office, if it can be assumed that single visa for each entry would have been given anyhow. If there is no history of you successfully getting a visa, using it properly and leaving the country according to the terms, chances are low that you will get a multiple entry visa. This is why the Border agency recommends to apply for a multiple entry visa only after you have applied and used a single entry visa already.

The UK border agency [lists the following points](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/visiting/general/apply/) as consideration for long term (and therefore multiple entry) visa:

> - whether you can show a frequent and sustained need to come to the UK (such as family links or an established business connection);
> - whether your personal circumstances are likely to change significantly while the visa is valid - so you should give us as much evidence as possible that your circumstances will remain the same;
> - whether you have shown that you can support yourself in the UK without public funds, and that you intend to leave the UK at the end of each visit; and
>     your previous travel history as shown in a current valid passport.

The first point is easiest proven with previous single-entry visa as mentioned above. The second point should be confirmed by providing your study documents so they know that you can remain as a student in the UK. The third point would be granted if you can provide a bank document showing that you have enough money to afford living the UK without the need for a job. Lastly, if you can show in your passport that you have frequently traveled to other developed countries and left them again according to the visa in the passport, your chances are even better.

Comment: My reading is that the OP has (or had, given the age of the question) a student visa for the UK. The question was about Schengen visas, perhaps for school holidays.

Answer (score 2):

I recently applied for Schengen visa for the first time and have been given multiple entry visa valid for a year by French Consulate...

Judging by the documents they asked for, the chances are higher if you:
1. are employed with regular income (docs - financial st, payslips, employment cert)
2. long-term travel insurance... by long-term I mean something like at least a year or so... (docs - travel insurance from the bank, company or private)
3. depends on the consulate of-course...

Having said this, multiple-entry visa is not guaranteed but there is no harm is requesting for multiple-entry visa because you will get single-entry visa if all the documents are correct and you requested for multiple entry visa...