# How to fill questions 25, 29 and 30 for Multi entry Schengen visa form

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork

I am going to have two separate short trips(non consecutive) in June to two countries in Schengen zone. I am trying to fill in a form for multi entry Schengen visa. But the form seems to be compiled for single entry visa. I am not quiet sure how to fill in answers for the following questions.

```
25. Duration of the intended stay or transit
Indicate number of days
```

Should I just enter the total like 9 days? Or something like 4 + 5. Or maybe 4 and 5

```
29. Intended date of arrival in the Schengen Area
```

This one should I write 1st June? Or 1st June and 15th of June.

```
30. Intended date of departure from the Schengen Area
```

Same for this just 20th of June? Or both 4th and 20th of June

See the link for the full PDF form here http://se.vfsglobal.co.uk/pdf/VISA_FORM-PDF_FORMAT.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form is read by a human, so you can write anything you like, as long as it's clear.  Since there's no place to explain why you want multiple entries, I would write the data for both trips in each field:

```
Trip #1: 4 days, Trip #2: 5 days
#1: June 1, #2: June 15
etc.
```

As you're probably aware (and this may not affect you), [multiple entry visas are not usually granted to first-time applicants](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5538/1893), but the worst that can happen is that they'll only grant you a single entry.

Comment: `multiple entry visas are not usually granted to first-time applicants`, not entirely correct. France is most liberal in allowing for Schengen visas, multiple entries with visa valid for more than 4-5 months, even for first time ones. Other EU countries, not at all.

Comment: As I said, "usually", and I'm pretty sure the odds of getting an exception rely much more on your application details (how do you justify needing a multiple entry?) than on the country you're applying to.

Comment: Thanks @jpatokal, Though i couldn't add multiple trips into the form because it doesn't allow it on VFS website. But I've added put those in the cover letter. And I got the visas already. :)

Comment: can we submit a cover letter as well ?