# Can I apply for 2 years Schengen Visas first Time?

Tags: schengen, long-stay-visas, nigerian-citizens

I am from Nigeria.
I have a question I want to ask, As a first timer, can I apply for 2 years Schengen visa up front for multiple entries?

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer just now, but take a look at [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5538/does-applying-for-a-multiple-entry-schengen-visa-instead-of-a-single-entry-the-f?rq=1) and [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39955/applying-for-german-schengen-visa-for-several-years-duration?rq=1). Your question isn't the same as them, but some of the answers are relevant for your situation.

Comment: There is no such thing as a two year Schengen visa though. The OP appears to be interested in long stay visas, and these are still the purview of the individual countries.

Comment: @KristvanBesien That's possible, I was wondering about that. There is however such a thing as a two-year Schengen visa, they can be valid for up to five years.

Comment: @relaxed: It depends on what you mean with "two years". A Schengen Visa allowing you to stay 2 years in the Schengen Area does not exist. You need a national visa for that. I was under the impression that this is indeed what the OP wanted.

Comment: @KristvanBesien I mean a visa that's valid for two years, no more no less. A two-year Schengen short-stay visa would still be limited to stays of 90 days in any 180-day period. National visas tend to be limited to one year or less, longer stays are typically covered by residence permits.

Comment: @Relaxed: Yes, but the OP tagged his post with "long-stay-visas", which gave me the impression that he was inquiring about that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get to specify a duration of validity on the standard form. The only dates you submit are those of your first trip to the Schengen area. What you can do is check the box asking for a multiple-entry visa and provide evidence of your need to travel to the Schengen area regularly. If you have a very specific and very convincing reason to want a two-year visa (as opposed to the generic flexibility afforded by a multiple-entry visa), you could write a letter to explain that and attach it to your application but there isn't really a way to apply for a two-year visa. Depending on your personal situation, it would be unlikely to get that on a first application and the dates of validity of your visa are still entirely up to the consulate.

If granted, a multiple-entry visa would go beyond the dates of your first trip and typically be valid for at least 6 months. The recommandations of the [Handbook](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/default/files/c-2020-395-commission-implementing-decision-annex_en.pdf) are not always followed but the EU Commission recommends issuing a one-year visa first, to be increased to two and then three years on renewal. UK residents sometimes get five-year visas on the first application, even without asking for it, but that doesn't help you if you reside in Nigeria.

Comment: Emphasis on "personal situation". The chances of getting a more flexible visa (or even to get a visa at all) increase with your (demonstrable) wealth, revenues, ties to your country, travel history, etc. A 50-year old CEO of a large company with millions in the bank is a lot more likely to get it than a 20-year old unemployed with barely enough money to pay for the flight. Also remember that given the current situation with lockdowns, quarantines and whatnot, visa applications are considered with a lot more suspicion these days than they were in the past.